# Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial. Failed test in Chapter 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm a newbie working through Michael Hartl's Tuby on Rails Tutorial and I have a couple of failed items in a test in Chapter  9.

Running RSPEC test returns:

```
sis-macbook-pro:sample_app Lagaspi$ bundle exec rspec spec/
...................................FF................................

Failures:

1) Authentication authorization in the Users controller visiting the edit page 
 Failure/Error: before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `user' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2::Nested_3::Nested_2::Nested_1:0x007fca6433d3b8>
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:72:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) Authentication authorization in the Users controller submitting to the update action 
 Failure/Error: before { put user_path(user) }
 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `user' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2::Nested_3::Nested_2::Nested_2:0x007fca6434db50>
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:77:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.85 seconds
69 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:73 # Authentication authorization in the Users controller visiting the edit page 
rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:78 # Authentication authorization in the Users controller submitting to the update action
```

My authentication_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

subject { page }

describe "signin page" do
before { visit signin_path }

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign in') }
it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
end

describe "signin" do
before { visit signin_path }

describe "with invalid information" do
  before { click_button "Sign in" }

  it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
  it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

  describe "after visiting another page" do
    before { click_link "Home" }
    it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
  end
 end

 describe "with valid information" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before { sign_in user }

  it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
  it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user)) }
  it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
  it { should have_link('Settings',    href: edit_user_path(user)) }
  it { should have_link('Users',       href: users_path) }
  it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

  describe "followed by signout" do
    before { click_link "Sign out" }
    it { should have_link('Sign in') }
  end
 end
end

describe "authorization" do

describe "for non-signed-in users" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  describe "when attempting to visit a protected page" do
    before do
      visit edit_user_path(user)
      fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
      fill_in "Password", with: user.password
      click_button "Sign in"
    end

    describe "after signing in" do

      it "should render the desired protected page" do
        page.should have_selector('title', text: 'Edit user')
      end
    end
  end
  end

   describe "in the Users controller" do

    describe "visiting the edit page" do
      before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
      it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
    end

    describe "submitting to the update action" do
      before { put user_path(user) }
      specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
    end
  end
  end

  describe "as wrong user" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
  before { sign_in user }

  describe "visiting Users#edit page" do
    before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
    it { should_not have_selector('title', text: full_title('Edit user')) }
  end

  describe "submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action" do
    before { put user_path(wrong_user) }
    specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
  end
  end
end
```

Here's line 73 from above

```
it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
```

And line 78 from above

```
specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
```

Any ideas? I'm really stuck as to what this means.Thanks Si.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On line 50 you have

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
```

But :user is no longer available by the time you reach line 73 because you close off the describe block that :user is defined within in line 68. Same thing on line 77 where you try to use it again.

My recommendation is to move the **let(:user)** to the top of the spec so you only need to define it once instead of including it throughout the spec. Failing that, define it again on line 71 (the line after **describe "in the Users controller" do**)

---

Potential solution is defining let(:user)..... at the top so you only need to define user once instead of in each block

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "authentication" do
  subject { page }
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  ...
```

Comment: OK, can you explain where or what the "top of the spec" is? Sorry i'm a newbie! Simon

Comment: Understood the bit about Line 71. Redefined it again but the same problem persist. Still don't understand what "top of the spec means".

Comment: Try restarting rails server. This may also help you put it into context: https://github.com/jeremydt/sample_app/blob/master/spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, but I really don't know what it has to do with Rails Server - and I don't understand what context you are trying to help me understand with your code. Sorry...

Comment: Hey, OK now! Thanks Jeremy. Top of the spec! I'll remember that Thanks!

Comment: And I see what you were doing with the code now too. Is that DRY?

Comment: yep, spot on :) Best to avoid duplicating the code if you can get away with defining it once!

Comment: Simon, would you please go back and accept the answer to my other question and accept this one as well.http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work