# Michael Hartl Ruby on rails tutorial chapter 9 - test fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on hartl's Tutorial. Currently chapter9. 
When i run test I get this error:

```
c:\rails_project\sample_app>bundle exec rspec spec/

Failures:

1) Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users when attempting to visit a
protected page after signing in should render the desired protected page
Failure/Error: visit edit_user_path(user)NameError:undefined local variable or
method `requests' for #<UsersController:0x37cff38>
# ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:36:in `store_location'
# ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:44:in `signed_in_user'
# ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:57:in `block (5 levels)
in <top (required)>'

2) Authentication authorization in the Users controller visiting the edit page
Failure/Error: before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
NameError:undefined local variable or method `requests' for 
#<UsersController:0x439d430>
# ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:36:in `store_location'
# ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:44:in `signed_in_user'
# ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:75:in `block (5 levels)
in <top (required)>'

3) Authentication authorization in the Users controller Submitting to the update
action Failure/Error: before { put user_path(user) } NameError: undefined local
variable or method `requests' for #<UsersController: 0x44f78d0>
# ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:36:in `store_location'
# ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:44:in `signed_in_user'
# ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:80:in `block (5 levels)
in <top (required)>'

Finished in 9.33 seconds
70 examples, 3 failures, 3 pending
```

My Authentication_pages_spec.rb file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do
    subject { page }

    describe "signin page" do
      before { visit signin_path }

      it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sign in') }
      it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
    end

    describe "signin" do

      before { visit signin_path } 

      describe "with invalid information" do
        before { click_button "Sign in" }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

        describe "after visiting another page" do
          before { click_link "Home"}
          it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
        end
     end

     describe "with valid information" do     
       let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } 
       before do
       fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
       fill_in "Password", with: user.password
       click_button "Sign in"
    end

    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
    it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
    it { should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user)) }
    it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
    it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

    describe "followed by signout" do
      before { click_link "Sign out" }
      it { should have_link('Sign in') }
    end
  end
end

describe "authorization" do

  describe "for non-signed-in users" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

    describe "when attempting to visit a protected page" do
      before do
        visit edit_user_path(user)
        fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
        fill_in "Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Sign in"
      end

      describe "after signing in" do

        it "should render the desired protected page" do
          page.should have_selector('title', text: 'Edit user')
        end
      end
    end
  end

  describe "in the Users controller" do

    describe "visiting the edit page" do
      before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
      it { should have_selector('title', text: "Sign in") }
    end

    describe "Submitting to the update action" do
      before { put user_path(user) }
      specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
    end
  end


  describe "as wrong user" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
    before { sign_in user }

    describe "visiting User#edit page" do
      before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
      it { should_not have_selector('title', text: full_title('Edit user')) }
    end

    describe "submitting a PUT request to the User#update action" do
      before { put user_path(wrong_user) }
      specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) } 
    end
  end    
 end
end
```

I've found that problem is similar to one showed in [Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial. Failed test in Chapter 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154967/michael-hartls-ruby-on-rails-tutorial-failed-test-in-chapter-9) 
but this solution doesn't work in my case. Anybody got idea?

Comment: you'll need to add the code for UsersController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sessions_helper.rb` file contains a typo:  `requests` instead of `request`.

See:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-and-response-objects

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just a shot in the void but you have typo in SessionsHelper.store_location. Change 'requests' to 'request'.